# jquery mobile ui-input-btn custom icon

Tags: jquery-mobile

Using jquery mobile, ui-input-btn....

```
<div class="ui-input-btn ui-btn ui-icon-alert ui-btn-icon-top">
   <div class="buttonText">Service<br/> Interruptions</div>
   <input data-enhanced="true" value="Service Interruptions" type="button" id="service_interruptions">
</div>
```

I would like to use a custom icon.

Can this be done with this control?

If so, please provide a sample.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom class to wrapping div and then override `background-image` and `background-size` of that class using `:after` pseudo selector.

```
<div class="ui-input-btn ui-btn ui-custom-icon ui-btn-icon-top">
   <div class="buttonText">Service<br/>Interruptions</div>
   <input data-enhanced="true" value="Service Interruptions" type="button" id="service_interruptions">
</div>
```

```css
.ui-custom-icon:after {
  background-image: url('icon.png');
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/t9bsadLm/)**