# How to get desired view of the icon using JQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I wark on my Mobile project and I use jquery mobile library version 1.4.5.

I have this png image:

[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
.ui-icon-measure {
    background-image: url(img/length_measure.png);
}

#measureControl {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 3em;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#measureButton .ui-icon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 13px;
    right: 13px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Here is HTML code:

```
<div id="measureControl" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="measure" id="measureButton" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
</div>
```

Here how it looks in the view:

[image]

But I want it to be like that:

[image]

Any idea what do I have to change in the code above to get desired view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26588671/1771795 http://stackoverflow.com/a/27356680/1771795

Answer (score 0):

The code below will produce this:

[image]

```
.ui-icon-measure:after {
    background: url(img/length_measure.png) no-repeat !important;
}

#measureControl a {
  padding: 20px;
}

#measureControl {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 3em;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 9999;
    border-radius: 13px;
}
```